# Populating a combolist automatically with data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Can anyone help please, I am trying to populate the data automatically to my combobox without having to push any button, but by the dropdown control.....

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (comboBox1.AllowDrop == false)
   {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30");
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Problem FROM PROBLEMT", conn);

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();

      SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
      ad.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Problem FROM PROBLEMT", conn);
      ad.Fill(ds, "Problem");

      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
      //Biding the data with the control
      BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
      bs.DataSource = ds;
      bs.DataMember = "Problem";

      DataGridView dvg = new DataGridView();
      this.Controls.Add(dvg);
      dvg.DataSource = bs;

      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Problem"]);
      }
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a `}` and I hardly believe that SelectedIndexChanged is the best place to populate a combobox. Since obviously you are learning, try to put your code on a button, once it is working fine from the click of the button, you can look for a better place to it, like the form load for example.

also what exactly is the problem? does it give an error?

Comment: I have a working button, it works perfectly when I click on it, then it populates the data to the combobox

Answer (score 0):

first create method for fetching data and load in combobox like this

```
    protected void LoadCombo()
    {

           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30"); 
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Problem FROM PROBLEMT", conn); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
            ad.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Problem FROM PROBLEMT", conn); 
            ad.Fill(ds, "Problem"); 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; 
            dataGridView1.DataBind(); 
        for (int X = 0; X <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; X++)
        { 
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[X]["Problem"].ToString()); 
        }
```

}

now on page_load call this method

```
protected void Page_Load()
{

if(ispostback)
 {

}
else
{
 LoadCombo();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question on how to populate a combobox automatically:

```
             private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                  using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection())
                   {
                    sc.ConnectionString= "database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30";
                    sc.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                     {
                       DataTable data = new DataTable();
                       sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, TypeProblem FROM eL_Section", sc);
                       sda.Fill(data);

                       comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
                       comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
                       comboBox1.DataSource = data;

                       comboBox2.ValueMember = "TypeProblem";
                       comboBox2.DisplayMember = "TypeProblem";
                       comboBox2.DataSource = data;


                     }


             }

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
              {
            cn.ConnectionString = "database=KnowledgeEssentials;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30";
            cn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                  {
                    DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM UserT", cn);
                    da.Fill(dat);



                    comboBox3.ValueMember = "UserName";
                    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "UserName";
                    comboBox3.DataSource = dat;

                  }
              }


        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'knowledgeEssentialsDataSet.ProblemT' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.problemTTableAdapter.Fill(this.knowledgeEssentialsDataSet.ProblemT);
     }
```